# Xpath unable to Locate Nested Frame Elements

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

There is a problem that occurs with Xpath to Find Elements of Nested Frame. My code is :

```
<html>
<head>
<frameset border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0">
<frame noresize="" name="main" src="main.py">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div id="cboxOverlay" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="colorbox" class="" style="padding-bottom: 57px; padding-right: 28px; display: none;">
<div id="main_loading" class="main_loading"></div>
<div id="spin_loading" class="spin-loading"></div>
<div id="page_header">
<div id="header2">
<div id="daemons_controller.py" class="header2_menu_div" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="main_report.py" class="header2_menu_div" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="manage_host.py" class="header2_menu_div" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="main.py" class="header2_menu_div"></div>
<div id="header2_div" style="display:none;">
**

    <div id="login_user">
    <img title="User" alt="" src="images/new_icons/user.png" style="width:16px;height:16px;">

**
<span>
</div>
</div>
<div id="user_options">
<div id="ubr_sub_menu" class="sub-sub-menu" style="right:auto;">
<div id="ubre_sub_menu" class="sub-sub-menu" style="right:auto;">
<div id="idu_sub_menu" class="sub-sub-menu" style="right:auto;">
<div id="header3">
<div id="container">
<div id="events_logs_box" style="display: none;">
<div id="footer">
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</body>
</html>
</frame>
</frameset>
<pixelperfectlastoverlay id="ppReloadLastOverlay"></pixelperfectlastoverlay>
</html>
```

**Xpath=//div[@id='login_user']**
The results gives an empty result .
I need the location of that id For my selenium tool to locate the Elements. Is there any way to locate frame by Xpath Locator.

Comment: `$driver->switchTo()->frame($driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('main')))`

Answer (score 2):

Use this method to find the element inside iframe:

```
driver.switchTo().frame((WebElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe")));
```

Now you are inside the iframe, you can find any element in the normal way because you are already inside the iframe. If you want to switch to the parent window, use this:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath, the problem might be because you're using () instead of []

```
//div[@id='login_user']
```

Comment: It Doesn't work that problem occur due to nested frame .Problem is due to nested frame.There are any method to find location of elements in nested frame